# How to handle app installed, uninstalled, upgrading events?

Tags: 2013, development, sharepoint-addin

I am following this blog post

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2013/10/02/ftc-to-cam-custom-actions-and-property-bag-entries.aspx

On the video and the download it shows how to handle the app installed event, when you set Handle installed to true, VS will a

```
public SPRemoteEventResult ProcessEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
        {
            SPRemoteEventResult result = new SPRemoteEventResult();
            using (ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.CreateAppEventClientContext(properties, false))
            {
                if (clientContext != null)
                {
                    clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    // Add custom actions to the site
                    new DeployManager().AddCustomActions(clientContext);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
```

But this same method will execute for installed, uninstalled and upgrading.

How can I differentiate between the 3 events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find out my self

just this switch

```
 switch(properties.EventType)
            {
                case SPRemoteEventType.AppInstalled:
```

Answer (score 2):

App events are written inside the method `ProcessEvent` of the service class and `properties.EventType` can be compared with `SPRemoteEventType` to check for the type of event. For example:

```
public SPRemoteEventResult ProcessEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
{
    SPRemoteEventResult result = new SPRemoteEventResult();
    if (properties.EventType == SPRemoteEventType.AppInstalled)
    {
    }
```